# Error encounter while export eclipse product

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Error occurred while collecting items to be installed.

**An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
 session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
 No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.objectweb.asm,5.0.1.v201404251740**

I installed osgi.bundle and import but error while export eclipse product.

**Java version**: 7u67, **OS**: Mac OS,

**Eclipse SDK Version**: 4.3.2

Answer (score 1):

I removed some plugin and after that I install another plugin in eclipse so it created some problem in osgi.bundle.

So I just uninstall eclipse from Mac and reinstall it and problem is solved.